# Removing entire column from .csv file without column titles - simple question

Tags: python, database, csv, algorithmic-trading, binance

I simply want to remove columns 6 to 11 entirely from the .csv file. Implementing solutions found online hasn't reaped any fix unfortunately. Most solutions delete. columns identified by their column title, however, my .csv file doesn't have column titles as it is easier for the future without them.

```
from binance.client import Client
import config, csv
import pandas as pd

client = Client(config.apikey, config.apisecret)

candles = client.get_klines(symbol='ETHUSDT', interval=Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1HOUR)

csvfile = open('1hour_dec2020_2021.csv', 'w', newline='')

candlestick_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')


candlesticks=client.get_historical_klines('ETHUSDT', client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1HOUR, "1 Dec 2020", "1 Jan 2021")

for candlestick in candlesticks:
    candlestick_writer.writerow(candlestick)

csvfile.close()
```

Example row from .csv file:
`1502942400000,301.13000000,302.57000000,298.00000000,301.61000000,125.66877000,1502945999999,37684.80418100,129,80.56377000,24193.44078900,47039.70675719` 
which corresponds to the Binance kline response

Removing unwanted columns would preferably result in: - timestamp, o,h,l,c,v
 `1502942400000,301.13000000,302.57000000,298.00000000,301.61000000,125.66877000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `itemgetter()` to pick the required values from each row. In your case they are contiguous so you could also use a simple slice:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from binance.client import Client
import config, csv

required_cols = itemgetter(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)        # specify required columns 
client = Client(config.apikey, config.apisecret)

with open('1hour_dec2020_2021.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    candlestick_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    candlesticks = client.get_historical_klines('ETHUSDT', client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1HOUR, "1 Dec 2020", "1 Jan 2021")

    for candlestick in candlesticks:
        candlestick_writer.writerow(required_cols(candlestick))
        
        # or just use a slice if contiguous
        # csv_output.writerow(candlestick[:6])
```

Using `with()` avoids the need to also add a `close()`